# iOS web app providing quota error on first AppCache download

Tags: ios, html5-appcache, iphone-standalone-web-app, quota

I am using HTML5 AppCache functionality in my web app. The total size of the files included in the cache manifest is 74mb. My understanding is that when you use <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"> in the <head> of your document and add the page to your Home Screen, iOS will treat it like a native app and disregard the 50mb Safari limit. However, when I open the Home Screen app for the first time, on my iPad running iOS7, it provides and error for exceeding the quota for web storage when it gets 3/4s of the way through. If I close the app and reopen a second time, the files will successfully complete downloading.

Is this a bug in iOS? Is there a work around, or some way to force iOS to remove the initial quota? Right now, I am having to open and download the files twice to get the files downloaded properly.